# Cron, Email, Performance

Tags: php, performance, email, cron

I am building a system for my client. It's a lot like www.getafreelancer.com.
There are 2 types of user: Service Provider and Service Buyer.
Service Buyers post projects.
Service Providers are notified of any new projects posted, which fit into their classifications.

Assume:
There are approx 100 qualifications. Service Provider can choose 10-15 qualification.
Now approx 100 projects are posted daily. And there are 1 million service provider.
And problem is we have to send email notifications to the service providers matching their chosen qualifications with the project category. (For all 100 projects daily).

It would be like proceeding user by user. Checking their qualification with the project category and sending them email. How can I send 20 * 1 million = 20 million emails daily?

(Currently there won't be 1 million users. But programming must be done with future requirements)

Please provide some suggestions.

My question is: Will I need any special hardware to send 1 million emails?

Comment: not a real question, please rewrite to make it a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the way you pose the question, it's a little hard to figure out what you want.

If you want to send email in near-real-time, life is fairly simple.  Some buyer has a need, and as soon as they post it, you send out a bunch of notifications.  This will be hard to scale, but the pain will come on the email delivery side.  Simply generating a list of providers to inform is fairly trivial assuming your database design and infrastructure is less than awful.

If that's what you're doing, you just want to make sure that you've got your email delivery platform set up in a smart way.  Design your infrastructure so your core system can easily delegate batches of email to N slave servers that can handle doing some mail-merge and give you enough SMPT throughput.

If you want to send email periodically, so that providers receive just one email with several jobs, you'll want to think about things a little differently.

In this case, consider an architecture based around segmentation of your list of providers, and database replication to handle the read-load.

In this model, a buyer posts a job.  Your main database gets updated, and some number of slaves get the data via replication.  Each slave is responsible for keeping providers up-to-date via email.  Every N hours, each slave reads from its dedicated, read-only, database and handles its segment of users.

You'll need to work out the details of re-segmenting your providers when you bring a new notification system online.  For instance, when you add your third notification system, it should end up serving approxmiately 1/3 of the load from each of the two existing ones.

Comment: I dont have enough knowledge of slave servers. But your answer does seem logical. Thank you.

Comment: My pleasure.  Mail delivery can be a huge headache.  Since your client will, in all honesty, probably never have a million providers, you should do your best to just plan ahead, without worrying too much about the details.  The fact that you imagine these emails going out via cron as opposed to during the creation of the job post means you're on the right track.  From there, continue to abstract things where you think you might need to multiplex in order to scale.

Answer (score 1):

That is a *lot* of email. First of all, it's unlikely you will ever be sending out that many emails so I wouldn't architect your system for that kind of volume. You should consider configuring your service so that fewer emails are necessary (daily summary, more selective targeting, rss feeds). But even if you're sending out 500,000 emails per day, you're going to need a heavy duty infrastructure or pay an ESP like VerticalResponse a *lot* of money. Free mail transfer agents (MTAs) include Postfix and SendMail. Commercial options include Strongmail and PowerMTA. With that much email, you'll probably need to watch out for spam complaints (depending on how your project review process). ReturnPath is useful for that.

Comment: It was helpful. I am planning to move certain things to RSS. Thank you.